# How do I show output from a script or program in Ubuntu 17.10 top-bar the way BitBar does for Mac OS X?

Tags: customization, gnome-shell, 17.10, top-bar

> The [BitBar app](https://getbitbar.com/) lets you put the output from any script or program right in your Mac OS X menu bar.

Image for reference:
[image: Image for reference]

I'm trying to add icons/data on Ubuntu top-bar the way BitBar does for Mac. Clicking on icon should display a widget which is customizable and which can be used to display sports score, weather etc.

Is there any api available for this?

Answer (score 3):

There is something similar to BitBar for GNOME shell, an extension called Argos.

> Argos is a GNOME Shell extension that turns executables' standard output into panel dropdown menus. It is inspired by, and fully compatible with, the BitBar app for macOS. Argos supports many BitBar plugins without modifications, giving you access to a large library of well-tested scripts in addition to being able to write your own.

You can get this extension from [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/) or its [GitHub page](https://github.com/p-e-w/argos).

Comment: DOESN'T WORK ANY MORE